# google spreadsheet function in query

Tags: string, select, indexing, google-sheets

I am trying to make a query in Google Spreadsheets of form

```
    QUERY(data_tables;"select B where A='"&A30&"' ");
```

where `'"&A30&"'` is some string value (name of a person). I would like to retrieve the value of `'"&A30&"'` by using `INDEX(data,30)` (`data` is named range for values of column `A`). Any ideas?

In other words, how can one embed a function call within google spreadsheets query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to replace the A30 reference with the INDEX formula:

`=QUERY(data_tables;"select B where A='"&INDEX(data;30)&"'")`

This formula assumes that your `data_tables` range includes columns A & B

I'm not clear why the `january!C8:AG10` part of your formula is for though - can you clarify?

Comment: does the formula I've suggested work as it stands then?